# partial orders homework

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a HW question

Let $R_1$ be a partial order on a set $A_1$ and $R_2$ be a partial order on a set $A_2$. Define a relation $R_3$ on the set $A_3 = A_1 \times A_2 = {(a_1,a_2) : a_1 \in A_1, a_2 \in A_2} $ by $(x_1,x_2) R_3 (y_1,y_2)$ iff $x_1R_1y_1$ and $x_2R_2y_2$ . Show that $R_3$ is a partial order on $A_3$

I am looking for some hint on how to start. Does this have something to do with lexicographic order ?  If so then do I need to be showing $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_2 R_2 b_2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to verify all the axioms of partial orders hold. Different books define them differently, but a standard definition would be a reflexive, antisymmetric, transitive relation. I'll prove one of them and you can do the rest as the proof is the same.

Reflexivity: Let $(a,b)\in A_1\times A_2$ then $aR_1a, bR_2b$ as $R_1,R_2$ are partial orders and hence reflexive. Thus by definition $(a,b)R_3(a,b)$.

Comment: thanks so much, this helps a lot.

Comment: one quick question to show anti symmetry I said: $(a,b), (c,d)\in A_1 \times A_2$ then $aR_1c$ and $cR_2d$ whenever $a=c$. Also $bR_2d$ and $dR_2b$ whenever $b=d$. So $(a,b)R_3(c,d)$ and the relation is anti-symmentric. Does this sound as a reasonable proof for anti-symmetry

Comment: You are proving the implication backwards. I.e. you want to show that if $ (a_1,b_1)R(a_2,b_2)$ and $(a_2,b_2)R(a_1,b_1)$ then $(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)$ however the way your argument is structured makes it look like you are arguing from the premise $(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)$.

A little bit of re-arranging should sort it out though.